# What causes could there be for data randomly not being saved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC website and there is a problem that occurs at random (and only on one server it seems) whereby the user navigates to an edit page which contains a few text fields and a submit button, changes some valid data in one of the fields and clicks the submit button but sometimes instead of the data saving and returning the user to the view details page (as it's supposed to), the edit page is displayed again and it saves only after clicking the submit button a few more times again.

Given the data being entered into the textboxes is valid, and given this problem cannot be reproduced on the other servers or local development copy of the website, what possible causes could there be for this? Could it be something related to resources on the server?

How would you go about investigating this in order to find out what's causing this?

Note; it's not possible to debug the code because it's on another server. I can use the same database but the problem still cannot be reproduced.

Comment: ..and of course you have all of the appropriate logging infrastructure in place to debug this.. yes? Start by checking the event log on the server. Monitor the application pool and see if it's crashing..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look at the event logs when this problem occurs. What other kind of logging do you mean? (other than event log and checking application pool)

Comment: Generally, we have varying logging levels that can be turned on and off from testing -> staging -> live servers. For example, `DEBUG` level logging logs almost everything. Whereas `FATAL` will only log very very bad stuff. `DEBUG` is enabled on testing.. slightly restricted on our staging servers, and only `FATAL` is enabled on the live servers. If for some reason one of the live servers is failing for unknown reasons.. we will flick it to `DEBUG` on the live server for 15 minutes then turn it back off. Then inspect the logs to see where exactly it was all failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps I would recommend:

1. Set a breakpoint in the corresponding controller, right at the top of the logic, and see what is being passed to the controller.  Then, follow the logic down to see where it is getting kicked out.
2. Open your browsers debugger and view the network traffic.  See exactly what you are sending to your controller.  This might shed some light on the reason(s) for the failed update.

Comment: Your second point is helpful thanks for the suggestion. As I said in the question I can't debug the code because it's on another computer.

Comment: Ah, missed that part.  Yeah, the network panel in Chrome is by far my most used debugging tool (next to console :P).  My guess is some values aren't getting serialized properly and are being rejected because the model isn't valid, returning the user back to the edit screen (pretty default behavior).  Hope you get it all sorted out!